# How to parse NaNs from tikzplotlib

Tags: pgfplots, tikzplotlib

I am making plots in Python and then export them to LaTeX using `tikzplotlib` library.  The problem is that `tikzplotlib` converts pairs with (at least one) `NaN` value to `-- --` as shown below

```
\addplot [draw=black, forget plot, mark=o, only marks]
table{%
x  y
1.75 -3.2
2 -3.2
2.25 -3
2.5 -2.9
-- --
-- --
};
```

LaTeX responds by issuing the error

```
! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '--' as a floating point number, sorry. The unreadable part was near '-'..
```

Is it possible to teach `pgfplots` to ignore `--` as `NaN`?  Or maybe teach `tikzplotlib` to export `NaN`s as `NaN`?

Comment: See `\pgfplotstableread` from pgfplotstable, and use `string replace` (page 40).  Use blanks (empty string) for NaN.  BTW, can tikzplotlib generate a comma delimted file?

Comment: @JohnKormylo OK, I figured out that you mean `pgfplotstable` package.  I tried `\pgfplotstableset{columns/y/.style={string replace={--}{NaN}},columns/x/.style={string replace={--}{NaN}}}` to no avail.  I don't see any possibility to create comma delimited file in the `tikzplotlib` documentation.

Comment: `externalize_tables=True` for `tikzplotlib` will place the data in separate text files as i understand it, you could find and replace `--` with `nan` in that file.

Comment: Interesting.  `\pgfplotstabletypeset` can read the file using `[string replace={--}{}]` with no errors, but `\pgfplotstableread` and `\pgfplots` both generate the errors no matter what I do.

Comment: Actually, `\pgfplotstableread[ignore chars={-}]{table.dat}\mytable` got reid of the errors.  It also got rid of all the negative numbers.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.  Thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, but a MWE for anyone who wants to experiment.

```
\begin{filecontents}{table.dat}
x  y
1.75 -3.2
2 -3.2
2.25 -3
2.5 -2.9
-- --
-- --
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string replace={--}{}]{table.dat}% works as expected

\pgfplotstableread[string type, string replace={--}{}]{table.dat}\mytable
\pgfplotstabletypeset{\mytable}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot [draw=black, forget plot, mark=o, only marks]
  table{\mytable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realised that Python as a programming language is much more flexible, so I simply excluded `NaN` data using

```
pyplot.scatter(x[~numpy.isnan(y)],y[~numpy.isnan(y)])
```

where `x` and `y` are `numpy` data arrays.